# For each of the following functions, find all local maximum and minimum points (Solution Verification)

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, maxima-minima

This is from Calculus by Michael Spivak, 3rd Edition, Chapter 11, problem 5. The solution published in the Answer Book seems to be incomplete. I think my solution is right and just want to verify.

> 11-5. For each of the following functions, find all local maximum and minimum points.
> (iv) $f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1,   &x = 1/n\text{ for some $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$} \\
> 0,  &\text {otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$

Here is the Answer Book solution and my proposed edit:

> (iv) All $1/n$ for $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ are local maximum points, and all other $x$ are local minimum points.

**Revision** All $1/n$ for $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ are in $[0,1]$, and are local maximum points (including $1$). All other $x$ in $[0,1]$ are local minimum points (including $0$). All $x$ not in this interval are both local maximum and local minimum points.

Comment: (ii) 

Suppose  $x=3/4$ is a local maximum. This means that exists a neighborhood $E$ of $3/4$ such that for any $x\in E$ we have $f(x)<1/4$. This is false because any neighborhood od $3/4$ contains at least a number that in lowest terms has a denominator greater that $4$.

Comment: The number you describe $p/q$ has denominator $q > 4$ and $f(p/q) = 1/q < 1/4$. This does not contradict $3/4$ being a local maximum.

Comment: Right! I meant *lower* than $4$

Comment: For the case of $x = 3/4$, if you use $\delta < 1/1000$ for example, you're not going to get a $p/q$ in this interval with $q \leq 3$. We can always find $p/q$ for bigger and bigger $q$'s, but not for smaller ones.

Comment: ($\delta = 1/12$ is sufficient, as this is the distance to $2/3$, the nearest $p/q$ with $q < 4$)